# Permission denied when I try to transfer file using scp -r

Tags: ssh, nginx

I am getting an error when I run this code:

```
 scp  -r ./build/* rose@IP_address:/var/www/mywebsite.com/html
```

```
Permission denied(publickey)
lost connection
```

It worked the first time but won't when I want to apply some changes to my create-react-app website.

Here is a snippet for

```
scp -vvv  -r ./build/* rose@IP_address:/var/www/mywebsite.com/html
```

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "IP_address" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to IP_address [IP_address] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/rose/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/rose/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/rose/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/rose/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/rose/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/rose/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/rose/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
```

Please help.

Comment: The private key `scp` is trying to use to authenticate you seems to be missing.

Comment: So how can I go about this?

Comment: Generate a key on your remote (IP_address) using `ssh-keygen` and copy that file to the place where you're running this command

Comment: I have already generated a key:   ` -rw------- 1 rose rose  381 Sep 10 09:28 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 rose rose 1675 Sep 11 07:03 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 rose rose  405 Sep 11 07:03 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 rose rose  222 Sep 11 09:22 known_hosts`

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution to this. I went to

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and changed `PasswordAuthentication no` to `PasswordAuthentication yes`

and `PermitRootLogin no` to `PermitRootLogin yes`

Then after running `sudo systemctl restart sshd`, and running `ssh user@IP_address`, it worked.